# ngrx selector subscription raising event multiple time ...with real value in store then undefined and then empty value

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx, ngrx-store

I have a project in which i have implemented ngrx store.

my store contain cart as a item list.

I have added selector for this

```
const getUserState=(state:AppState)=>state.user || {};
export const getCarts=createSelector(getUserState,fromUser.getCart)
```

but when i subscribe  for selector, it get called multiple time(in my case 3 times first time with correct value ,second time undefined and third time with empty value)

my subscription is like bellow

```
 this.cartSubscription=this.store.select(getCarts).subscribe((cart)=>{
      console.log('---------in dashboard--------')
      console.log(cart);
    this.addedItems=cart;
    });
```

Is there any Idea why it is happening.[image]

Comment: Do a console.log in the reducer where you change the user state and see how many times is called and with what values. Also use Redux Devtools to have a look at what actions are called.

Comment: What you have above looks ok, so without any other context it would be quite tricky for someone to figure out what is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the action was making the state empty.

**Reason for this behavior:**

Since i have handled that action in effect but i missed default switch case for action type in reducer.

Thats why it was returing me empty state after that action dispatched.

```
export function reducer(state:State=initialState,action:userActions){
 switch(action.type){
     case uActions.GET_ALL_FOOD_ITEMS_FINISHED: 
                 return Object.assign({}, state, { foodItems: action.payload});
      default: return state;
}
}
```

Default Case saved me :)